# NextJs renders both components when using higher order components (HOCs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, higher-order-functions

Im creating a dashboard page and if you are not logged in the HOC should use the Login component instead. I created a very simple example for proof of concept. The problem is that I am logged in but I see a flash of the login component before seeing the dashboard. I thought maybe is was strictMode so I turned that off but that didn't work. Then I read that it will do that in dev so I did an export to a static site and I still see the login rendering before the dashboard loads.

Here is my _app.tsx

```
import protectedRoutes from './../components/hocs/protected-routes';

function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
export default protectedRoutes(App)
```

Here is my protected-routes file

```
const protectedRoutes = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
 return (props: any) => {
    const Router = useRouter();
    const [accessGranted, setAccessGranted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

        if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
            setAccessGranted(true);

        } else{
            Router.replace('/');
            setAccessGranted(false);
        }

    }, []);

    if (accessGranted) {
        return <Dashboard content={<WrappedComponent {...props} />}/> 
    } else {
        return <Login/>
    }
  };

 };

 export default protectedRoutes;
```

Comment: It happens because your _initial_ state for `accessGranted` is `false`, so it will always render the `<Login>` component first.

Comment: Yeah you should do something like this: `const [accessGranted, setAccessGranted] = useState(!!localStorage.getItem("user"));`

Comment: @Dominik if I try that I get: `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

Comment: Oh yes SSR... try: `const [accessGranted, setAccessGranted] = useState(localStorage ? !!localStorage.getItem("user") : false);`

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same `localStorage is not defined`

Comment: You should consider not rendering anything until _after_ the access check. For instance, you could set `accessGranted` initial state to null and not render anything when it's in that state.

Comment: I tried that too but then there is about a 1/2 second flash of white

Comment: You'll always get a flash of something because the check is made on the client-side.